# fstream.open() not appending to existing file

Tags: c++, file-io

Here is my main function:

```
void main()

{
    Student s1 = Student(12, "Ali");
    Student s2 = Student(1, "Hassan");
    Student s3 = Student(8, "Bilal");

    s1.WriteFile();
    s2.WriteFile();
    s3.WriteFile();
}
```

while WriteFile() function is:

```
void WriteFile()

    {
        fstream fileWriter, fileReader;

    string string_line;

    fileWriter.open("D:\A111.txt");

    while (!std::getline(fileReader, string_line).eof())
    {

    }

    cout << GetRoll_No() << " , " << GetName() << endl;

    fileWriter << GetRoll_No() << " , " << GetName() << endl;

    fileWriter.close();
    fileReader.close();
}
```

Whenever I call it, it only shows me following in A111.txt

8 , Bilal

So why doesn't it append it at the end of existing file. Please note that filereader is added only later on while trying for a solution, it gives same error without eof() as well

Comment: What makes you think an `fstream` will default to append mode if you don't tell it to do so?

Comment: So you didn't read the [`fstream` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/), correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was was asked without any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot to pass mode argument to open() function . you are on the right track ,just make this little change:

```
 fileWriter.open("D:\A111.txt",ios::app);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `open` method should be used like this if you want to append:

```
fs.open ("test.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

Note the: `std::fstream::app`